# How PEMDAS,BODMAS are true in this case

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

If we look at this expression
$\frac{A}{B + C}$
It looks like it is simply
$A ÷ B + C$

But the calculator does it as
$A ÷ ( B + C )$

Why does the calculator do it like this as in the first place there are no brackets.

I have attached calculator result screenshot.

[image: calculator]

Comment: $a/b+c$ is not the same thing as $\frac{a}{b+c}$.

Comment: The calculator has it right. The PEMDAS rule does not cover all situations, and this is one.

Comment: I suppose it’s a convention that $\frac{a}{b+c}$ means $\frac{a}{(b+c)}$. The notation seems to make it clear that $b$ and $c$ are grouped together in the denominator, so people usually don’t bother to say this explicitly.

Comment: It's not clear how the calculator input works. Given the red bar in the denominator, maybe having entered `100/` put the calculator into a "visual fraction mode" with the cursor in the denominator, so that all of `25+5` appeared in the denominator. (Perhaps it's easier to *keep* input in the denominator until expressly "escaped" than to try to go back into it.) Consequently, the *typed sequence of characters* `1 0 0 / 2 5 + 5` ends up being interpreted as  $\frac{100}{25+5}$. This isn't so much a violation of PEMDAS/BODMAS as it is a quirk of the interface design.

Comment: "$\frac{a}{b+c}$" is not ambigous at all ! It cannot be misunderstood ! For "$a/b+c$" the rule is clear : Division before addition , again no misunderstanding possible. The calculator does it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

On many calculators nowadays, when you press the ÷ button or the fraction "-" button, you automatically stay in the divided part until you choose to come out of it. So if you want to do $A ÷ B + C,$ you have to press on your calculator:

$A$

÷

$B$

$>\quad $ (Right Arrow (to come out of the divided part)

$+$

$C$.

*Why* this is the case? I do not know. But it's not a big deal, right? Just get used to it.

Comment: This can be avoided by starting with $C$ , then we can just enter "C+A:B" to get the desired expression "$c+\frac{a}{b}$"

Comment: @Peter of course. But my answer is helpful anyway as there are other times when it is unavoidable that you need to escape fraction division input.